# How to automatically clean up workspace directories of deleted Jenkins Jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins instance with hundreds of jobs. Recently I noticed that the storage space on the server was almost full and the main reason was - the JENKINS_HOME/workspace/ directory included multiple workspace folders of deleted jobs (freestyle projects).

- Even if I manually delete all redundant folders, they will start accumulating again.
- I can not use the [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup/) to delete Workspace after each build of each project or just periodically delete the whole 'workspace' directory, as for many projects, the workspace overview in Jenkins is needed.
- I can write some bash script for this job, that compares the JENKINS_HOME/workspace/ and JENKINS_HOME/jobs/, but this is a bit 'hardcoding'.

Is there a Plugin that can periodically delete leftover workspaces?
Or maybe I can configure Jenkins to also delete workspaces when a Project is deleted? (all I could find is an [open bug ticket](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-22240), that was last updated in 2018)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a separate Jenkins that runs periodically and does the cleanup? You can write some simple groovy code to get a list of Jobs configured, and compare it to what you have in workspace directory and delete.

Comment: this seems to be a reasonable approach, I will try to do something like that.